# How to use a proxy website to view some other websites in C#?

Tags: c#

Suppose several websites are filtered in my region, and in order to get some specific information on that pages, i need to use a proxy website such as ([Thisone](http://www.hotpanda.info)) to bypass the filtering.
How can i send my `URL` to these kind of sites and get the result?
How can i search in the resulting content for specific term or object (image, flash, etc)?

Comment: What have you tried? How does a browser behave when you visit an URL trough that site? Can you mimic that behavior using a WebClient? Please show some more research effort.

Comment: WebClient is of no use , so is WebBrowser.since they only accept a url or ip address of one website(the first one) and there is no way to feed  the first website through these controls as far as i know,The website im trying to use to bypass the censorship,also encodes the urls,I dont know how i am supposed to give the second url to the the first website !

Comment: Don't write it off so soon. If a regular web browser can create a given request, it should be able to recreate that request using a WebClient. Take a look at the traffic the site sends using Fiddler for example, and try to emulate that through code.

Comment: @CodeCaster the problem doesn't seem to be making the web request - it's what to do once the request has been made. Hossein wants to interact with a web page programmatically *after* is has been loaded.

Comment: @MattDavey the site linked simply contains a form. If you can capture the POST being made and recreate that using a WebClient you can simply read the response.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's a great suggestion, I see where you're coming from now! If you write up an answer you can count on an upvote from me :)

Comment: @MattDavey I can't be bothered, feel free to adapt the idea in your answer. :-)

Comment: @CodeCaster:Thanks,But will that work on the similar websites?since  these websites are censored after sometime,I need to replace them with others which has not been discovered and filtered.I have no idea if all of these sites follow a specific method for achieving their goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the site you mentioned does not provide any API of any kind that you can call from C#. Probably your best option is to automate manual entry of the url using a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Watin](http://watin.org/).

Comment: Thanks,This is the kind of thing  im exactly after.which of these are better ( and free of course?)

Comment: Well, both of these tools are designed for automated testing - in that respect Selenium is more mature. However, you are using them for a different purpose, so perhaps Watin is a better option as it is slightly more lightweight (and it is .NET)

Answer (score 0):

The `WebClient` and `WebBrowser` components in .NET automatically use the system Internet Explorer network and proxy settings (set via the Control Panel > Internet). If you set them there then you're all set.

If you use `WebBrowser` I don't know (off my head) if you can manually override the proxy settings, but with `WebClient` you set the `WebClient.Proxy` property.

Comment: Thanks,But I don't have access to any proxy service(that is Ip and port combinations),I have souple of anonymizer websites which i can use.I am trying to find a way to work with these.